# Google datastore modelling

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have two entities. Categories and Products. Each product can have many categories and each category can belong to many categories. I would like to be able to return all products and for each one to have all the categories it belongs to and their parent categories. Is datastore a good option for something like this?

example Product response:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "shoes",
    categories: [{
        id:1,
        ordinal:1
    },{
        id:2,
        ordinal:1
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assume you meant 'Datastore' where you wrote 'dataflow'

It depends if you want to query later based on categories or not.

## In case you won't need to query based on categories

I'd suggest defining your categories in a model (with the appropriate parent/child relationships) and then adding each category to a product in a LocalStructuredProperty. Datastore will save as a blob but will reconstruct the category entity model when you retrieve the product. You could also add a JsonProperty with a serialized string containing the category structure for each product. For example:

```
[
  0: {
    category: 'Electronics',
    subcategories: ['Smartphones', 'Telephones', 'Gadgets']
  },
  1: {
    category: 'Apple',
    subcategories: ['iPhone']
  }
]
```

[Read more about the LocalStructuredProperty and the JsonProperty here (for Python client library)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference).

---

## If you need to query based on categories

Then you should use a StructuredProperty. Create a model to define your categories and their ancestor paths. Then you add one or more categories (along with their parents) to the Product entity when you instantiate it.

The [Entity Property Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#structured) in Datastore documentation has a good example of how to implement it (in Python, but also available for other languages). And here's how you [filter for StructuredProperty values](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#filtering_structured_properties).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes I meant datastore. I need to query events by their categories.